# I need to return the output of each .py file (dict) parallelized with the subprocess package in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, subprocess

I have 02 .py files that I'm parallelizing through the subprocess command. The outputs of each .py file are dictionaries. I need that after finishing the code, the console returns me the 02 dictionaries (01 of each function). Below, 03 codes: the parallelization (subprocess) and the .py files.

Code 01: The parallelization using subprocess

```
import subprocess
import json

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'Magalu_Telefonia.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'Magalu_Eletrodom.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Captura a saída dos processos
output1, error1 = p1.communicate()
output2, error2 = p2.communicate()

# Decodifica a saída como JSON e converte para um objeto Python
dict1 = json.loads(output1.decode())
dict2 = json.loads(output2.decode())

# Imprime os dicionários de saída
print("Dicionário de saída de file1.py:")
print(dict1)
print("Dicionário de saída de file2.py:")
print(dict2)
```

Code 02: Magalu_Telefonia.py

```
#Importando as bibliotecas necessárias
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import math
import re
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# In[1]. CRIANDO O DICIONÁRIO PARA EXPORTAÇÃO
dic_produtos = {'marca':[], 'preco':[], 'loja':[], 'categ':[], 'link':[], 'foto':[], 'id_cat':[], 'id_loj':[]}

# In[2]. MAGALU

## TELEFONIA ##

def scraping():
    
    url_base = 'https://shopping.smiles.com.br/telefones-e-celulares/magazine-luiza/magazineluiza?initialMap=seller&initialQuery=magazineluiza&map=category-1,sellername,seller'
    executable_path = r'C:\Users\vinig\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path)
    browser.get(url_base)
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-totalProducts--layout")))
    qtd = element.text
    browser.quit()
    index_final = qtd.find(' Produtos')
    qtd = int(qtd[0:index_final])
    ultima_pagina = math.ceil(int(qtd)/10)
    
    for i in range(1,3):
            url_pag='https://shopping.smiles.com.br/telefones-e-celulares/magazine-luiza/magazineluiza?initialMap=seller&initialQuery=magazineluiza&map=category-1,sellername,seller&page='+str(i)
            headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
            executable_path = r'C:\Users\vinig\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
            browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path)
            browser.get(url_pag)
            produtos = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"shoppingsmiles-product-0-x-contentItem")))
            html = browser.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml' )
            keyword = "contentItem"
            produtos = soup.body.find_all(class_=re.compile(keyword))
                
            for produto in produtos:
                marca = produto.find('div', attrs={'class':"shoppingsmiles-product-0-x-itemName shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-itemName shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-itemName--categoriasProdutos"}).text
                preco = produto.find('div', attrs={'class':'shoppingsmiles-product-0-x-itemPrice shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-itemPrice shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-itemPrice--categoriasProdutos'}).text
                index_inic = preco.find('R$')
                #index_final = preco.find(',')
                preco_liq = preco[index_inic+3:]
                for item in produto.find_all('img'):
                    foto = item['src']
                itens = produto.select('a')
                link = [item['href'] for item in itens]
                link = str('shopping.smiles.com.br')+str(link[0])
        
                dic_produtos['marca'].append(marca)
                dic_produtos['preco'].append(preco_liq)
                dic_produtos['loja'].append('magalu')
                dic_produtos['categ'].append('telefonia')
                dic_produtos['foto'].append(foto)
                dic_produtos['link'].append(link)
                dic_produtos['id_cat'].append('1')
                dic_produtos['id_loj'].append('1')
                   
            browser.quit()
       
    return dic_produtos

dic_produtos = scraping()
```

Code 03: Magalu_Eletrodom.py

```
#Importando as bibliotecas necessárias
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import math
import re
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


# In[1]. CRIANDO O DICIONÁRIO PARA EXPORTAÇÃO
dic_produtos2 = {'marca':[], 'preco':[], 'loja':[], 'categ':[], 'link':[], 'foto':[], 'id_cat':[], 'id_loj':[]}

def scraping2():
    
    ##############################################################################################
    ## ELETRODOMÉSTICOS ##
    url_base = 'https://shopping.smiles.com.br/eletrodomesticos/magazine-luiza/magazineluiza?initialMap=seller&initialQuery=magazineluiza&map=category-1,sellername,seller'
    headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
    executable_path = r'C:\Users\vinig\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path)
    browser.get(url_base)
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-totalProducts--layout")))
    qtd = element.text
    browser.quit()
    index_final = qtd.find(' Produtos')
    qtd = int(qtd[0:index_final])
    ultima_pagina = math.ceil(int(qtd)/10)
    
    try:
        
        for i in range(1,4):
            url_pag='https://shopping.smiles.com.br/eletrodomesticos/magazine-luiza/magazineluiza?initialMap=seller&initialQuery=magazineluiza&map=category-1,sellername,seller&page='+str(i)
            headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
            executable_path = r'C:\Users\vinig\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
            browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path)
            browser.get(url_pag)
            produtos = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"shoppingsmiles-product-0-x-contentItem")))
            html = browser.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml' )
            keyword = "contentItem"
            produtos = soup.body.find_all(class_=re.compile(keyword))
                
            for produto in produtos:
                marca = produto.find('div', attrs={'class':"shoppingsmiles-product-0-x-itemName shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-itemName shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-itemName--categoriasProdutos"}).text
                preco = produto.find('div', attrs={'class':'shoppingsmiles-product-0-x-itemPrice shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-itemPrice shoppingsmiles-search-result-0-x-itemPrice--categoriasProdutos'}).text
                index_inic = preco.find('R$')
                #index_final = preco.find(',')
                preco_liq = preco[index_inic+3:]
                for item in produto.find_all('img'):
                    foto = item['src']
                itens = produto.select('a')
                link = [item['href'] for item in itens]
                link = str('shopping.smiles.com.br')+str(link[0])
        
                dic_produtos2['marca'].append(marca)
                dic_produtos2['preco'].append(preco_liq)
                dic_produtos2['loja'].append('magalu')
                dic_produtos2['categ'].append('eletrodom')
                dic_produtos2['foto'].append(foto)
                dic_produtos2['link'].append(link)
                dic_produtos2['id_cat'].append('3')
                dic_produtos2['id_loj'].append('1')
                
            browser.quit()
    
    except:
        print('próximo item')

    return dic_produtos2

dic_produtos2 = scraping2()
```

The error is in the return: the JSON Expecting Value message appears instead of the dictionary, which is the output of each function in the .py file. Maybe I'm wrong to use JSON to decode the result. The error image is below:

[image]

Comment: Neither of your subprocesses are actually producing any output.  You'd need to do something like `print(json.dumps(dic_produtos))` so that the main process has something to work with.

Comment: The dic_produtos isn´t avaiable.

Comment: What do you mean, it "isn't available"?  You're assigning a variable on the last line of each subprocess - which is utterly pointless, as that variable will immediately disappear.  You have to output it, instead.

Comment: Tks for your attention. When placing the code `print(json.dumps(dic_produtos))` at the end of the code returns an error saying that the name 'dic_products' is not defined.